# How to override settings.settings variable by app.config variable

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

How can I change (or override) a settings.settings variable by adding a variable to the app.config on production?

Is this possible anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to directly reference the applicationSettings you're trying to override and explicitly specify the property that has a replaced value.

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- section definitions for all elements in <configuration> tag -->
  <configSections>
    <!-- section group, meaning: there will be a <applicationSettings> tag in you configuration-->
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <!-- defines that there will be a <appname.Properties.Settings> tag inside your <applicationSettings> tag -->
      <section name="appname.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>
    <appname.Properties.Settings>
      <!-- name of the property you want to override -->
      <setting name="setting1" serializeAs="String">
        <!-- new value -->
        <value>new string value</value>
      </setting>
    </appname.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where does `appname` come from?

Comment: We migrated to .net 5 and we are using app.config. From our test environment before we override settings for other projects like that 
<appname.Properties.Settings>
but after migration it doesn't work... Do you have any ideas.

Comment: For anyone reading @AlexKvitchastiy's question it appears that in .Net 5.0 the naming convention dropped the `.Properties.` part so its just `<yourAppName.Settings>`

Comment: @Scottymac oh man, if it's true and it's works in .NET 5 u make me happiest person in this world, because I tried lot of different workarounds!

Comment: @Scottymac idk man, it doesn't work. Also when I create settings file, it by default create <yourAppName.Properties.Settings> in app.config...
Even if I try to override it from my test project> I tried yourAppName.Settings and yourAppName.Properties.Settings nothing work...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope of the settings. If its an application scope setting changing its value in app.config is sufficient.

However, if its a user scope setting then the value present in app.config is just the default used to new users and every user that already used the application will have the currently used value stored in a separate file, the user.config, so changing the value in app.config will have no effect to users that already run the application once.

Due to this changing the value of an user scope setting can be a troublesome task. You can check the following answer for more information on changing a user scope setting:

[Changing User Scope Application Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593881/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-a-settings-settings-value/6594013#6594013)

Answer (score 0):

Use different config files for production and for you. Basically on production you would compile in RELEASE, so if you  use Visual Studio for it, use post build events to copy RELEASE config file in case you prepare a build for production.

I would prefer this instead of changing it from the code, as for *someone else* is much easier to see the differenc in config file, then going deep into the code to find all the `if/else` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For an application scope connection string value:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="appname.Properties.Settings.setting1" connectionString="test string" providerName="dbProvider"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score -1):

Only through code:

e.g.

```
 if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["overridethis"].ToString()))
 {
     //use overridden value
 }
```

If however, your issue is maintaining different configuration values in different environments, then I would use AppSettings instead.

You can then use a developer override file.

```
 <appSettings file="..\user.config">
```

See http://www.compiledthoughts.com/2005/03/overriding-webconfig-app-settings-with.html

Comment: The OP is asking about Settings.settings and not the `ApplicationSettings` section.