# Override <applicationSettings> defaults

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-express, application-settings

I have an old .asmx web service being consumed by a web app. VS 2015 generates the code and inserts some settings into web.config like so:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Foo.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://localhost/WebReporting/ReportRenderer.asmx</value>
    </setting>
  </Foo.Properties.Settings>
<applicationSettings>
```

Basically, I want to replace this in the default development config to point to the local IIS express instance, and then use transforms to generate the correct output for a release build (exactly as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608240/how-to-override-settings-settings-variable-by-app-config-variable)):

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Foo.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://localhost:31571/ReportRenderer.asmx</value>
    </setting>
  </Foo.Properties.Settings>
<applicationSettings>
```

However, this change doesn't actually change the setting at runtime. In fact, the setting that's actually used is obtained from the DefaultSettingValueAttribute on the property of WebApp.Properties.Settings:

```
namespace Foo.Properties {
  internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
    ...
    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.WebServiceUrl)]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("http://localhost/WebReporting/ReportRenderer.asmx")]
    public string Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer"]));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the web.config has no effect on this result, only by commenting out the DefaultSettingValueAttribute does it return null.

I still have some of the old-style "appSettings" in this web app, so would that be conflicting with the newer settings format? I'm not sure what else could be going on.

Edit: trying to remove the element before changing it as suggested below has no effect:

```
<Foo.Properties.Settings>
  <remove name="Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer" />
  <setting name="Foo_WebReporting_ReportRenderer" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://localhost:31571/ReportRenderer.asmx</value>
  </setting>
</Foo.Properties.Settings>
```

Comment: In your local web.config file, use the <remove> tag to remove just one setting; <clear /> will remove all inherited settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309404(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Your suggestion has no effect. See my edit for the change I made.

Comment: Same question but for the defaults used in WPF.  It's the default value that's used, and I can't find a way to change it at runtime.